# kill: 5656 : arguments must be process or job IDs

Tags: linux, bash, redis

Having `redis-server` ON (launched with `redis-server &`).

Running this command in a terminal works perfectly:

```
kill -s SIGTERM "`pgrep redis-server`"
```

But in a script it outputs the following message and does not kill the process:

```
myscript.sh: line 17: kill: 1448
1452: arguments must be process or job IDs
```

(if I do: `pgrep redis-server` in this example it will outputs me `1448`)

My complete source script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -a "redis-server_must_be_ON" ]
then
  if [ "`redis-cli PING`" != "PONG" ]
  then
    redis-server &
    if [ "`redis-cli PING`" != "PONG" ]
    then
      echo "redis-server still not running while it should have been set on." >> /dev/stderr
      exit 1
    fi
  fi
else
  if [ "`redis-cli PING`" == "PONG" ]
  then
    kill -s SIGTERM "`pgrep redis-server`"
    if [ "`redis-cli PING`" == "PONG" ]
    then
      echo "redis-server still running while it should have been set off." >> /dev/stderr
      exit 1
    fi
  fi
fi
```

(Here if I replace the `pgrep redis-server` with some sort of mascarade like `pgrep bash1.sh` it also works fine).

Is my script correct, what do I miss ?

Comment: For completeness, does `ps aux | grep redis-server` return 1448 as the PID of the process?

Comment: Aren't you reinventing the wheel? Most systems have `service redis stop`, `systemctl stop redis`.

Comment: `username  1448  0.0  0.1  34880  4320 pts/1    Sl   14:17   0:01 redis-server *:6379` yep :/

Comment: @grawity, your commands returns me `Unit redis.service not found.`. I also tried to use the service like that: `/etc/init.d/redis-server start`, but with no incidences (no errors, but no process either) both with `start` and `stop`. However, `redis-server &` let me use it and do redis request finely.

Comment: Ok so `redis-cli shutdown` works. But, this is still weird that the same `kill` command does not work in a script.